# What does "unmasked flourish" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The true meaning of the Waterfall approach, then, is **unmasked <flourish/>:**
it’s actually about control, and melds beautifully with the contractor-control model of IT. The CIO wants to earn the seat at the table through demonstrating control over the chaos of IT delivery.

What does "unmasked flourish" mean in the above context? Is "flourish" used as a noun?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is saying that "the true meaning is unmasked." The word "flourish" may be a humorous attempt to imitate an HTML format command suggesting waving a flag to emphasize the statement. It would make more sense as </flourish> than as <flourish/>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Always very difficult to understand humor as a non native English speaker. The answer helps me a lot.